# Removal of mysql-replication tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Does MySQL need it's own specific [mysql-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql-replication) tag...as opposed to using [mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) ?

Comment: Make your case for or against.

Comment: @jcolebrand If I were tagging a question on mysql replication, I would use the dual tags 'mysql' and 'replication' instead of the single tag. If that was the standard way to tag, it would make `mysql_replication` unnecessary. I would suggest it as a synonym, but I don't think synonyms can belong to multiple tags (pulling in 2 master tags)

Comment: They cannot, you are correct (afaik). Which makes more sense? I think it makes more sense to use the "two tag system". Is there a command in MySQL with that long name?

Comment: Two tags make more sense to me as well...no command requiring that long tag. The wiki and questions assigned to it are just about replication within mysql (two tag standard!)