# Tag nuke mysql-upgrade

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, retag-request

Follow the logic of [`mysql-replication` this is a silly compound tag and should be nuked.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/removal-of-mysql-replication-tag)

Make `mysql-upgrade` a synonym of `upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

[mysql-upgrade](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql-upgrade) (19 questions) has been merged into [upgrade](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)

Comment: cool cool you the man.